# JavaScript in React to modify the DOM

Tags: css, reactjs, dom

I have a component with a `div.modal` that I would like to **transition** with CSS. The initial values are set for **w=0** and **h=0**, **transition is all, 1s**.

This component is a conditional render wihin another component named - `<Starter />`, which in turn is a component of `<Home />`.

I have tried this in a number of places however the DOM is not ready

```
{ document.getElementsByClassName('modal').style.width = 'auto' }
```

The component:

```
const JoinSign = () => { 
    
    return (
        <div id="overlay">
            <div className="modal">
            <h2>Join Sign in</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default JoinSign;
```

Comment: Not sure, but [React Transition Group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/) may be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried `useRef`? Also you might have forgotten index of your element - `document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach for me is just to add a class to modal and do a useEffect:

```
const JoinSign = () => { 

   const [additionalClass, setAdditionalClass] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => { //not sure it is required but 
        setAdditionalClass('open')
      }, 1);
      return () => setAdditionalClass('') //clean up function
    }, [])    

    return (
        <div id="overlay">
            <div className={`modal ${additionalClass}`}>
            <h2>Join Sign in</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default JoinSign
```

And you handle the animation with just plain css on .modal.open

Comment: Yep, that works R4ncid and I get it :)  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `width` property to a component dynamically

```js
    const JoinSign = () => { 
    
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(20);
    
    return (  
        <div id="overlay">
            <div className="modal" style={{width: width}}>
            <h2>Join Sign in</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default JoinSign;
```

and then change width using

```js
setWidth(50);
```

or when the component mounts

```js
    const JoinSign = () => { 
    
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(20);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setWidth(50);
    });

    return (  
        <div id="overlay">
            <div className="modal" style={{width: width}}>
            <h2>Join Sign in</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default JoinSign;
```

Comment: I get the width, but no transition.
.modal {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 2s;
}

Comment: @Ozbodd check out changes, you can dynamically change the width property

Comment: OK I see where are are going, but I want the animation to occur when the component mounts - Not on a  button event so not sure hwere tto apply setWidth()

Comment: @Ozbodd added example with useEffect